# Implicit parameter in Scalaz

Tags: scala, types, scalaz

I try to find out why the call [`∅` in `scalaz.ListW.<^>`](http://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/raw/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/ListW.scala) works

```
def <^>[B: Zero](f: NonEmptyList[A] => B): B = value match {
  case Nil => ∅
  case h :: t => f(Scalaz.nel(h, t))
}
```

My minimal theory is:

```
trait X[T]{
   def y : T
}

object X{
  implicit object IntX extends X[Int]{
    def y = 42 
  }
  implicit object StringX extends X[String]{
    def y = "y" 
  } 
}
trait Xs{
  def ys[T](implicit x : X[T]) = x.y 
}

class A extends Xs{
  def z[B](implicit x : X[B]) : B = ys //the call ∅
}
```

Which produces:

```
import X._

scala> new A().z[Int]
res0: Int = 42

scala> new A().z[String]
res1: String = y
```

Is this valid? Can I achieve the same result with fewer steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's all there is to it. You could remove `Xs` and retain the essence of the example:

```
object A{
  def ys[T](implicit x : X[T]) = x.y 
}
A.ys
```

The other interesting aspect of the use in Scalaz is that the type argument to `∅` is inferred from the expected type `B` of the expression.

I recently had to change `Zero` to be invariant in its type parameter. This actually breaks the infer-ability of this type argument in some cases; you can see this in this [example](http://gist.github.com/386283). There are a few related open tickets which will hopefully be solved by the changes on this [branch](http://github.com/adriaanm/scala/tree/topic/embeddings).